# Bit hacking and modulo operation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, low-level

While reading this: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseByteWith64BitsDiv

I came to the phrase:

> The last step, which involves modulus division by 2^10 - 1, has the
>   effect of merging together each set of 10 bits (from positions 0-9,
>   10-19, 20-29, ...) in the 64-bit value.

(it is about reversing the bits in a number)...

so I did some calculations:

```
reverted = (input * 0x0202020202ULL & 0x010884422010ULL) % 1023;

b = 74          :                                 01001010
b 
 * 0x0202020202 :       1000000010000000100000001000000010
   = 9494949494 :01001010010010100100101001001010010010100
  & 10884422010 :10000100010000100010000100010000000010000 
    = 84000010  :         10000100000000000000000000010000
  % 1023        :                               1111111111
    = 82        :                                 01010010
```

Now, the only part which is somewhat unclear is the part where the big number modulo by 1023 (2^10 - 1) packs and gives me the inverted bits... I did not find any good doc about relationship between bit operations and the modulo operation (beside `x % 2^n == x & (2^n - 1))`) so maybe if someone would cast a light on this it would be very fruitful.

Comment: The modulo doesn't "invert" the bits, it just "packs" the 4 bytes into one.

Comment: @RagingScallion You're right, bad wording from my side...

Comment: Just FYI, division operations (such as modulo) are very expensive on a CPU with fixed-point architecture. Now, you tagged your question as `low-level`, so I assume that it might be relevant in your case. If you **are** writing your code for that kind of processor, then you should really try to avoid using `%` or `/` (as I said, just FYI)... In addition, you may also want to look at http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Bit%20Reversal (no division operations involved). Although it shows an example for a 32-bit operand, I believe it should work fine for 64-bit operands as well.

Comment: N mod constant should not be expensive at all; the compiler can use similar trick to turn the division into reciprocal multiplication and more.

Comment: " I did not find any good doc about relationship between bit operations and the modulo operation (beside x % 2^n == x & (2^n - 1))) " -- what more do you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The modulo operation does not give you the inverted bits per se, it is just a binning operation.

### First Line : word expansion

b * 0x0202020202 = **01001010** **01001010** **01001010** **01001010** **01001010** 0

The multiplication operation has a convolution property, which means it replicate the input variable several times (5 here since it's a 8-bit word).

### First Line : reversing bits

That's the most tricky part of the hack. You have to remember that we are working on a 8-bit word : `b = abcdefgh`, where [a-h] are either 1 or 0.

```
b  * 0x0202020202 = abcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefgha
    & 10884422010 = a0000f000b0000g000c0000h000d00000000e0000
```

### Last Line : word binning

Modulo has a peculiar property : `10 ≡ 1 (mod 9)` so `100 ≡ 10*10 ≡ 10*1 (mod 9) ≡ 1 (mod 9)`.

More generally, for a base `b`, `b ≡ 1 (mod b - 1)` so for all number `a ≡ sum(a_k*b^k) ≡ sum (a_k) (mod b - 1)`.

In the example, `base = 1024` (10 bits) so

```
b ≡ a0000f000b0000g000c0000h000d00000000e0000 
  ≡ a*base^4 + 0000f000b0*base^3 + 000g000c00*base^2 + 00h000d000*base +00000e0000 
  ≡ a + 0000f000b0 + 000g000c00 + 00h000d000 + 00000e0000 (mod b - 1)
  ≡  000000000a
   + 0000f000b0 
   + 000g000c00 
   + 00h000d000 
   + 00000e0000 (mod b - 1)
 ≡   00hgfedcba (mod b - 1) since there is no carry (no overlap)
```