# Modulus and Binary Numbers

Tags: c++, binary, modulus

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    int index = 0;
    int val;
    int x;

    while (val != 0)
    {

    cin >> val;



    for (index = 1; index < 32; index++)
    {
        x = val * index - index / index;
        cout << x << " " << val << " " << index << endl;
        cout << x % 4 << endl;
        cout << x % 3 << endl;
        cout << x % 2 << endl;

    }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Why is it that when the input is <1, 2, 3, 4...> every 31st index is encoded in an algorithm similar to input 1, which is just index - 1; but the pattern is:

of twelves (1-12, 12 -24) [000, 111, 220, 301, 010, 121, 200, 311, 020, 101, 211, 321] , [000, 111, 220, 301, 010...repeating for input <1>;

of 31st index: [1]200, 111, 020, 301, 210, 121, 000, 311, 220, 101, 010, 321, 200...[13]

Why is the relation similar and is there a reason for this in binary?

Edit: To clarify question, when you take the remainder of a certain integer, and the relation becomes specific to each incrementation...is the reason for this because of binary and how the semantic is based on implementing a way to converge integer value to binary value? I know that high-level programming is using hash and communicating within programs...but the main idea is for the integer value to be binary specific...is this a binary specific operation or just some random algorithm that shows patterns in numbers?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Please clarify.

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047196/is-there-any-way-to-write-mod-31-without-modulus-division-operators

Comment: @mydiax How do you distinguish _binary input_ actually?

Comment: @mydiax Integer numbers are numbers, their binary representation is a totally [different kettle of fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kettle_of_fish).

Comment: Could you impose that a binary function via a pointer, to a hash and an emulated integer back and forth? (edit), emulating a binary to value of integer, then back to a different binary format i.e. binary >> int a >> binary(1) >> int b[index].mod

Comment: @mydiax None of this makes any sense. Not a word of it. It is all meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important fact:

```
12 mod 2 == 12 mod 3 == 12 mod 4 == 0
```

Another important fact, a little more abstract:

```
(x + y) mod k == ((x mod k) + (y mod k)) mod k
```

(Assuming x, y and k are all integers.)

From the second fact, we can deduce:

```
(x + 12) mod k == ((x mod k) + (12 mod k)) mod k
```

As it happens:

```
(x mod k) mod k == x mod k
```

And so now we know that

```
(x + 12) mod 2 == (x mod 2) + 0 == x mod 2
(x + 12) mod 3 == (x mod 3) + 0 == x mod 3
(x + 12) mod 4 == (x mod 4) + 0 == x mod 4
```

So the pattern of mods will repeat in a cycle of 12.

In general, the cycle length will be the Least Common Multiple of the divisors.

Comment: 2 * 3 * 4 = 24, not 12

Comment: @ajc2000: yeah, should have been lcm(2,3,4) but not worth the trouble explaining. Skipped directly to the mod. Thanks

Comment: I found that when starting with <input: 1> and <input : 31>, putting them in rows and columns, each pair of any number will give the first and last array of mods. So, 1 starts with 000, ends with 200, each number is like that no matter what, whatever it started with the column, row, of <input 1> and <input 31> is this what you're trying to tell me?

Comment: @mydiax: what i'm trying to tell you is that a little bit of arithmetic will explain what you are seeing. I encourage you to grab a pad of paper and a pencil and exercise your mathematical reasoning.

Comment: is this a structure complex? from when you combine logarithms such as, 
[g] as log (2 log x^log (n)) = log (n) + log (x) = 2? (log(x) * x^2 is just X because this is pertaining to square roots because [index::25] on any input gives me the row >input1<